# Import Google Chrome bookmarks from Windows into Mozilla Firefox in Ubuntu

Tags: firefox, google-chrome, bookmarks, ubuntu-12.04

I was a Windows user for last 5 years but wanted to switch into Ubuntu World. I saved too many (around 100) bookmarks into chrome while using Windows. Now I want to import those bookmarks into Ubuntu browser (Firefox).

How can I achieve this?

Comment: is there a reason you don't want to use Chrome in Linux? Enable Chrome Sync & your Chrome bookmarks from Windows install will be available in Linux

Comment: No it is not the concern but I wanted to learn it which probably can be done via some file manipulations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Export bookmarks from Google Chrome**

quoted from https://support.google.com/chrome/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=96816

> 1. Click the wrench icon on the browser toolbar.
> 2. Select *Bookmark manager*.
> 3. Click the *Organize* menu in the manager.
> 4. Select *Export bookmarks*.
> 5. Choose a location where you want your exported file to be saved, then click Save.
>
> Google Chrome will export your bookmarks as a HTML file.

**Import Bookmarks from an HTML file**

quoted from http://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/import-bookmarks-html

> 1. Click the Bookmarks button   on the right side of the navigation toolbar (Windows XP: click the *Bookmarks* menu) and select *Show All Bookmarks* to open the Library window.
> 2. From the toolbar on the Library window, click *Import and Backup* and choose *Import  Bookmarks from HTML...*.
> 3. In the Import Bookmarks File window that opens, navigate to the bookmarks HTML file you are importing and select the file.
> 4. Click the *Open* button. The Import Bookmarks File window will close.
> 5. Close the Library window.

Answer (score 1):

You can use some cross browser bookmarks sync service as [xmarks](http://www.xmarks.com/).

Comment: I heard about some file manipulation or file rewritten for this purpose but I don't know them. Can you suggest some different way. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

### How to Export Bookmarks from Chrome and Import into Firefox

**1. Export from Chrome**

Firstly, open **Chrome** and press <kbd>**Ctrl**</kbd>+<kbd>**Shift**</kbd>+<kbd>**O**</kbd> to open the **Bookmark Manager**. Now click the dropdown arrow beside **Organize**, select **Export bookmarks to HTML file...**, and now save the file somewhere you can find and access for the **Import into Firefox** step.

[image]

**2. Import into Firefox**

Secondly, open **Firefox** and press <kbd>**Ctrl**</kbd>+<kbd>**Shift**</kbd>+<kbd>**B**</kbd> to open the Library window. Now click the dropdown arrow beside **Import and Backup**, select the **Import Bookmarks from HTML...**, and now select the HTML file you saved in the first step by **double-clicking it** or highlighting it and selecting **Open**.

[image]